# Couchbase Java API getting ConnectException

Tags: java, json, couchbase, sql++, couchbase-java-api

I am creating a dummy JSON and trying to query it. I am doing that using JAVA. The code is as follows :-

```
import static com.couchbase.client.java.query.Select.select;
import static com.couchbase.client.java.query.dsl.Expression.s;
import static com.couchbase.client.java.query.dsl.Expression.x;

import com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket;
import com.couchbase.client.java.Cluster;
import com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster;
import com.couchbase.client.java.document.JsonDocument;
import com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject;
import com.couchbase.client.java.env.CouchbaseEnvironment;
import com.couchbase.client.java.env.DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment;
import com.couchbase.client.java.query.Query;
import com.couchbase.client.java.query.Statement;

public class AccessData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
                .queryEnabled(true)
                .build();
        Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(env, "127.0.0.1");
        Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("default", "");
        JsonObject testDataBlog = JsonObject.create().put("type", "blog").put("data", "blablabla");
        JsonObject testDataComment = JsonObject.create().put("type", "comment").put("data", "ho hey");
        bucket.upsert(JsonDocument.create("testDp4Blog", testDataBlog));
        bucket.upsert(JsonDocument.create("testDp4Comment", testDataComment));
        Statement statement = select("*").from("default").where(x("type").eq(s("blog")));
        Query createIndex = Query.simple("CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON default");
        bucket.query(createIndex);
        Statement withPlaceholders = select("*").from("default").where(x("type").eq(x("$1")));
}
}
```

On executing the above code, I am getting the following error :-

```
Apr 13, 2016 10:02:33 PM com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseCore <init>
INFO: CoreEnvironment: {sslEnabled=false, sslKeystoreFile='null', sslKeystorePassword='null', queryEnabled=true, queryPort=8093, bootstrapHttpEnabled=true, bootstrapCarrierEnabled=true, bootstrapHttpDirectPort=8091, bootstrapHttpSslPort=18091, bootstrapCarrierDirectPort=11210, bootstrapCarrierSslPort=11207, ioPoolSize=4, computationPoolSize=4, responseBufferSize=16384, requestBufferSize=16384, kvServiceEndpoints=1, viewServiceEndpoints=1, queryServiceEndpoints=1, ioPool=NioEventLoopGroup, coreScheduler=CoreScheduler, packageNameAndVersion=couchbase-java-client/2.1.0-dp2 (git: 2.1.0-dp2), dcpEnabled=false, retryStrategy=BestEffort, maxRequestLifetime=75000, retryDelay=com.couchbase.client.core.time.ExponentialDelay@5b80350b, reconnectDelay=com.couchbase.client.core.time.ExponentialDelay@5d6f64b1, observeIntervalDelay=com.couchbase.client.core.time.ExponentialDelay@32a1bec0}
Apr 13, 2016 10:02:36 PM com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint$2 operationComplete
WARNING: [null][KeyValueEndpoint]: Could not connect to endpoint, retrying with delay 32 MILLISECONDS: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:11210
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:712)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:208)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:281)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Apr 13, 2016 10:02:37 PM com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint$2 operationComplete
WARNING: [null][KeyValueEndpoint]: Could not connect to endpoint, retrying with delay 32 MILLISECONDS: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:11210
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:712)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:208)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:281)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Apr 13, 2016 10:02:38 PM com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint$2 operationComplete
WARNING: [null][KeyValueEndpoint]: Could not connect to endpoint, retrying with delay 32 MILLISECONDS: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:11210
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:712)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:208)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:281)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Apr 13, 2016 10:02:39 PM com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint$2 operationComplete
WARNING: [null][KeyValueEndpoint]: Could not connect to endpoint, retrying with delay 32 MILLISECONDS: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:11210
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:712)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:208)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:281)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.couchbase.client.java.util.Blocking.blockForSingle(Blocking.java:93)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster.openBucket(CouchbaseCluster.java:108)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster.openBucket(CouchbaseCluster.java:99)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster.openBucket(CouchbaseCluster.java:89)
    at AccessData.main(AccessData.java:21)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    ... 5 more
```

Any clues to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using pretty outdated versions of the server and the SDK, and developer preview versions!

I'd strongly advise you to do a fresh clean install of Couchbase Server 4.1.0 and to use the Java SDK in it latest version, `2.2.7`. A few things will have changed:

- you won't need the `queryEnabled(true)` when configuring the environment
- `Query` has been renamed `N1qlQuery`

The error you get indicates that when the client tries to connect on localhost, nothing answers (at least on port 11210). Can you check that the node is correctly up in the [web console](http://localhost:8091/)?

Once again, prefer installing Couchbase with 4.1.0. If you don't have any particular data to keep in your current instance, do a full reinstall (by removing the current installation first. see [here](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/install/install-uninstalling.html)).